# Exercise Order in a Push-Pull 2-Split

Tags: weightlifting, splits

I'm currently building myself a 2-Split Push-Pull workout routine and have a little struggle with the order in which to put the exercises. Three rules of thumb I was following with my previous Upper-Lower-Plans were:

1. Train from biggest to smallest muscle (e.g. start with Upper Back and end with Biceps).
2. Train one muscle group from start to finish (e.g. do Flyes after Bench Press, because it targets the same muscle).
3. Train Abs at the end of the workout in order to provide sufficient core stability during the workout.

This worked great for the Upper-Lower-Split I was doing, but with the new Push-Pull I'm having some trouble. The plan I want to pursue in the future:

**Push**

- Leg Press/Squat, 3x 8-10
- Lunges, 3x 10-12
- Single Leg Standing Calf Raises, 3x 8-10
- Bench Press, 3x 8-10
- Fly, 3x 10-12
- Shoulder Press, 3x 10-12
- Lateral Raise, 3x 12-15

**Pull**

- (Romanian) Deadlifts, 3x 8-10
- Seated Leg Curls, 3x 10-12
- Pull Ups, 3x 10-12
- Bent Over Row, 3x 10-12
- Reverse Fly, 3x 12-15
- Crunches, 3x 10-12

**Can I follow this workout routine as stated or should I switch the exercise order?** Obviously, exercises like Deads, Squats and Lunges have to be placed at the beginning of the workout (rule 1). But I'm unsure of then following with Calf Raise or Leg curls, respectivly (rule 2) or do these exercises at the end, because they train relativly small muscles (again, rule 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really doesn't matter on the order you do your exercises. There are plenty of theories on whether doing your big compound movements first is the best way to do things as you have more energy but there are a lot of professional bodybuilders who do their lifts when they are most fatigued or even mixing it up each week.

What it depends on when trying to build muscle and get results is your workout intensity and form but most importantly your diet.

Although the rules you have been following are the 'general' consensus when it comes to bodybuilding, it's not the MUST DO to build muscle.

To answer your question following the rules:

Calf raises can come anywhere as although part of your leg, they are rarely activated during lunges/squats however doing them straight after your legs phase is probably the best place for them (as you have it)

As for seated leg curls you would 100% train these after RD's as you're overloading your hamstrings and still engaging the glutes.